# metaMDS {vegan} distances instead of community matrix

Tags: r, vegan

The help file of `metaMDS` {vegan} mentions that one can also use a `dist` object instead of community data in the `comm` argument.

So if I run the following, why do I get different results? Am I doing something wrong here and is `metaMDS` ending up computing dissimilarities of dissimilarities?

```
library(vegan)
data(varespec)
vare_dist <- vegdist(varespec, method="bray")
vare_mds <- metaMDS(comm = vare_dist, autotransform = FALSE) 
# actually autotransform = FALSE doesn't seem to change the results
plot(vare_mds, type = "t")

vare_mds_2 <- metaMDS(comm = varespec, distance = "bray", k =2)
plot(vare_mds_2, display = "sites", type = "t")

# plots above are different and the stress values below as well
vare_mds$stress; vare_mds_2$stress
# [1] 0.1000211
# [1] 0.1843196
```

Fallowing this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629645/r-metamds-ordination-distances) I though that using the `autotransform = FALSE` would fix the issue. However, I think values are not that extreme to trigger a transformation need, so seems not to apply here. Also this [discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/metaMDS-NMDS-use-of-alternative-distances-td905826.html) didn't help me much. 
Specifically, I have a `dist` object from running `unifrac {picante}` and I thought I could use it in `metaMDS {vegan}`.
PS: unfortunately I'm not an ecologist and I'm trying my best to fallow the jargon. I can only ask for your extreme patience.

Comment: You don't need to speculate: the `metaMDS` output will tell you whether transformations were used.  Look at the `Data:`  row of the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, given the same options, `metaMDS()` called with dissimilarities and community will result in the same model *if started from the same random seed* (nMDS involves an iterative algorithm using random starting locations).

That you don't use the same random seed for both fits in your example is not the source of the problem here, however. Your two calls are actually resulting in different fits because the input data are different due to the defaults for `autotransform` with community data and dissimilarities.

`autotransform` *is* having a difference as it affects the data that actually gets converted to dissimilarities. Think of it as a pre-processing step, one that you didn't you when you created your dissimilarities. Hence you need to add `autotransform = FALSE` to the *second* call, the one with the community data.

If you run the following two calls

```
set.seed(1)
m1 <- metaMDS(comm = vare_dist, autotransform = FALSE)
set.seed(1)
m2  <- metaMDS(comm = varespec, distance = "bray", autotransform = FALSE)
```

you'll see that they are the same:

```
> procrustes(m1, m2)

Call:
procrustes(X = m1, Y = m2) 

Procrustes sum of squares:
8.882e-16
```

The above shows that the configurations are exactly equivalent up to machine precision, and the stress statistics are equal for both models

```
> m1$stress
[1] 0.1000211
> m2$stress
[1] 0.1000211
```

`metaMDS()` is designed as a wrapper to underlying functions that implement nMDS in a particular way (from `?metaMDS`, Details section)

> Function `metaMDS` is a wrapper function
>        that calls several other functions to combine Minchin's (1987)
>        recommendations into one command.

It makes decisions on the basis of the input data. Some of those decisions can'd be made for dissimilarities as, as is the case with `autotransform`, the are intended to be applied prior to the analysis.

Comment: Hi @Gavin Simpson. Thanks for your answer. I have noticed that when plotting the two models `m1` and `m2` in your example I get identical spread of points, but different nMDS axis coordinates. So, results are symmetrical with `m1` plot looking like a zoom-in of `m2` plot. Is that something I should be worried about?